# Mailform october CMS

Tags: octobercms

How can I create contact forms in octobercms? I find some settings in admin, but have no idia how to create form in backend. Maybe someone have simple example?

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention you want to show it in backed or fronted .. as in front-end you need to do it manually, I can suggest plugin and share a `plugin link` which can help you.

> if you want to show it in `back-end` you can use `form builder`

But i guess you want to show it in `front-end`

Just use `this plugin` and `extend it or / change its code` according to your need 
as there is not free from builder you can use to create fornt-end-forms right now.

> https://octobercms.com/plugin/zainab-simplecontact

let me know if you need more resources